# Unable to send email to too many recipients using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email

Am trying to send email(gmail) using `vb.net`, Below is part my code.

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(strUsername, DecryptPwd(strPassword))
    SmtpServer.Port = strPort
    SmtpServer.Host = strServer
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    Mail = New MailMessage()
    strInvName = "Product's List"
    Try

        mail.From = New MailAddress(strUsername, strInvName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        mail.To.Add(emailAddrs) '**this consists of 130+ recipients**'
        mail.Subject = strSubject
        mail.Body = ""
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\productList.pdf") = True Then
            mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Application.StartupPath & "\productList.pdf"))
        Else
            MsgBox("The Sale Invoice File Does Not Exists.Please Try Again", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "RStar")
            GoTo Quit
        End If
        mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
        mail.ReplyTo = New MailAddress(strUsername)
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("Product's List Sent Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStar")
        mail.Dispose()
    Catch exsr As SmtpFailedRecipientsException
        MsgBox("Mail not recieved by the recipient,Please check the email id again", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStar")
        mail.Dispose()
    Catch exfr As SmtpFailedRecipientException
        MsgBox("Mail not recieved by the recipient,Please check the email id again", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStar")
        mail.Dispose()
    Catch exse As SmtpException
        MsgBox(exse.Message)
        mail.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Sending Failed.Please Try Again", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "RStar")
        mail.Dispose()
    End Try
```

---

i'm sending to many recipients at a time. in my case i have *130 recipients* to send

am getting this error

```
  Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.5.3 Your message has too many 
  recipients. For more information regarding
```

- *How to solve this issue??*

**edit**

[Sending limits(GMAIL)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

Comment: How about using a loop and send e-mails to 30-40 reciepents at a  time? The error originates from the SMTP-Server, apparently it can't handle 130 e-mailadresses at a time.

Comment: @N55PEC right now i have changed the method to loop, but i wish to get a solution for it

Comment: you could get your own email server or use a paid email service that allows more recipients.  Have you tried putting the 'to' addresses on the BCC instead?  I'm not sure if that makes a difference with gmail's limitations.

Comment: Seeing that your using g-mail, you obviously can't change the SMTP-Settings. You could always try to find an alternative SMTP-Server. Or start using distribution groups ,those should count as 1 recipient (for some smtp-servers).

Comment: @ps2goat > Have you tried putting the 'to' addresses on the BCC instead? NO

Comment: Then can you try it...?

Comment: @ps2goat still the same, i think its not possible at this moment because of gmail's [sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

Comment: ah, good find.  So you'll need to find an alternate provider that allows you to do send to that many people or use a loop to send to groups of people.  Just remember that if you're sending with email addresses in the `To` field, all recipients can see all of the other recipients' display names and email addresses.  Using `BCC` will hide the other email addresses.